# Getting Div id in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an issue where in the Angularjs directive where the initialize() in the controller is called first before the template is rendered. That means I can't retrieve the dynamic id.

I am trying to have a different id for each map but currently crashing on the code below because of the dynamic id.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('addressMap-' + $scope.mapId), mapOptions);
```

Full Code, Any idea? cheers

```
app.directive('googleMap', function ($compile) {

var mapId = 1;
var linker = function (scope, element) {
    scope.mapId = mapId++;
};

return {
    require: '^addressBasedGoogleMap',
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        address: "=",
        zoom: "=",
        mapId: "="
    },
    template : '<div id="addressMap-{{::mapId}}" style="height: 200px;"></div>',
    link: linker,
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var geocoder;
        var latlng;
        var map;
        var marker;

        var initialize = function () {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: $scope.zoom,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('addressMap-' + $scope.mapId), mapOptions);
        };
        var markAdressToMap = function () {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': $scope.address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        $scope.$watch("address", function () {
            if ($scope.address != undefined) {
                markAdressToMap();
            }
        });
        initialize();
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to defer `initialize()` until `$scope.mapId` is present. One way to do it would be:

```
$scope.$watch('mapId', function(oldval, newval) {
    if (!oldval && newval) {
        initialize();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does not work. The template is still being rendered last

Comment: Hmmm,  have you tried wrapping `initialize()` in a `$timeout` so it is defered to another digest cycle and give you directive a chance to render.

Something like: `$timeout(initialize,0)`

Comment: that is a bad solution

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these.

**Solution 1:**

```
$scope.$$postDigest(function(){
  initialize();
 });
```

**Solution 2**

```
$timeout(initialize)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
function waitForDiv() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('addressMap-' + $scope.mapId);
    if (typeof elem == 'undefined') {
        $timeout(waitForDiv, 100);
    }
}

function () {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: $scope.zoom,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    waitForDiv();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('addressMap-' + $scope.mapId), mapOptions);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In directives and angular in general, you want reference to your elements prior to compiling or anything and avoid searching the DOM for them by id after the fact.

If you create the element that will contain your map you can avoid the $timeout you would need to wait for the digest - by already having reference to that element *_map*.

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rI6Jujk4bcWr8g1PLesd?p=preview)**

```
var map_el = '<div id="map-{{mapId}}" class="map"></div>';

var _link = function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
   var _map = $compile(map_el)(scope);
   el.append(_map);
   ctrl.addMap(scope, _map);
};

var _controller = function() {
   var m = this;
   m.addMap = function(scope, _map) {
     ...
     new google.maps.Map(_map[0], mapOptions);
   }
}
```